# Node JS, mongoDB - Route varible which was retrived from mongodb causing error, beacuse of &#39 characters stored along with the string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have two questions in particular

1. How to use a variable which was passed along with the route in client side Js.
2. How to fix this escape characters which was stored alongside with the strings in mongoDB as they are creating error.

Any type of best-practices, improvements or suggestions are appreciated.

Question 1 description :

This is how i am passing the route variable

```
 res.render('index', {weightEntries: weightEntries});
```

This is how i am using it in client-side Js (but i don't feel its the right way), I am using  `ejs` as templating engine

```
let weightEntrieslocal = [<%= weightEntries %>];
```

Question 2 description :

This is how i am creating a date string before inserting it into mongoDB

```
let d = new Date();
let months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
let dateString = d.getDate().toString() + " " + months[d.getMonth()].toString() + " " + d.getFullYear().toString();
```

when I retrieve the my documents from the mongoDB it is like this

```
{ weight: 84.4, datelabel: &#39;3 Feb 2021&#39; }
```

These `&#39;` characters are creating error.

Comment: What is your Database schema, I think you could use a DateField in mongodb

Comment: yeah, we can use datefield in mongo. But the problem was solved no worries, btw thanks man